# Ruby: Select a grouped array with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby

I have an array of transactions. I need to group the transactions by name and then select the group with the highest amount & more than 1 instance.

For example, if I have 1 transaction named "car" with an amount of $3000, and 3 transactions with "boat" totaling $1800, and 4 transactions with "house" totaling $500, the method will select boat because it is the highest amount group with multiple transactions.

```
@transactions =
 [{"amount"=>-3000, "name"=>"CAR"},
  {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
  {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
  {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
  {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" },
  {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" },
  {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" },
  {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" }]
```

Right now I have this but it selects based on length of name.

```
@transactions.group_by {|h| h['name'] }.max_by {|k, v| v.length }.first
```

How can I group, then sum, then select by highest amount in a group with multiple transactions.

Comment: Can you clarify something for us? All of your amounts are negative, so the sum for `"BOAT"` is -1,800 and the sum for `"HOUSE"` is -500, meaning the latter is greater than the former. Do you want the sum with the greatest absolute value, or the greatest sum of all absolute values? (Those will be the same if all values are negative, but different if some are positive and some are negative, i.e. |-10| + |5| ≠ |-10 + 5|.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of good answers here. I'd like to add that you can eliminate a lot of iteration by combining operations.

For example, rather than calculating the sums for each group in a second step, you can do that inside your `group_by` block:

```
sums = Hash.new(0)

groups = transactions.group_by do |t|
  sums[t["name"]] += t["amount"]
  t["name"]
end

p groups
# => { "CAR" => [ { "amount" => -3000, "name" => "CAR" } ],
#      "BOAT" => [ ... ],
#      "HOUSE" => [ ... ] }

p sums
# => { "CAR" => -3000, "BOAT" => -1800, "HOUSE" => -500 }
```

Next instead of doing `groups.select` to eliminate groups with only one member and then `min_by` to get the final result, combine the former into the latter:

```
result = groups.min_by do |k,g|
  g.size > 1 ? sums[k] : Float::INFINITY
end

p result[1]
# => [ { "amount" => -600, "name" => "BOAT" },
#      { "amount" => -600, "name" => "BOAT" },
#      { "amount" => -600, "name" => "BOAT" } ]
```

Because *everything* is smaller than `Float::INFINITY`, those groups with only one member will never be selected (unless every group has only one member).

And so...

### Solution 1

Putting it all together:

```
sums = Hash.new(0)

result =
  transactions.group_by {|t|
    sums[t["name"]] += t["amount"]
    t["name"]
  }.min_by {|k,g| g.size > 1 ? sums[k] : Float::INFINITY }[1]

p result
# => [ { "amount" => -600, "name" => "BOAT" },
#      { "amount" => -600, "name" => "BOAT" },
#      { "amount" => -600, "name" => "BOAT" } ]
```

### Solution 2

You could also combine all of this into a single `reduce` and iterate over the data only once, but it's not very Rubyish:

```
sums = Hash.new(0)
groups = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
min_sum = Float::INFINITY

result = transactions.reduce do |min_group, t|
  name = t["name"]
  sum = sums[name] += t["amount"]
  (group = groups[name]) << t

  if group.size > 1 && sum < min_sum
    min_sum, min_group = sum, group
  end
  min_group
end
```

Note that you could move all of those outside variable declarations into, say, an array passed to `reduce` (instead of `nil`), but it would impact readability a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
@transactions.group_by { |h| h['name'] }
             .map { |k, v| [k, v.inject(0) { |acc, cur| acc + cur['amount'] }] }
             .max_by(&:last).first
```

when you want a single value from `Enumerable`, you probably need `reduce` or `inject`.

---

See documentation on [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) for further info.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity:

```
[*transactions.each_with_object(
     Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {count: 0, total: 0} }
  ) do |h, memo|
    memo[h['name']].tap do |ct|
      ct[:count] += 1
      ct[:total] -= h['amount']
    end
  end.reject { |_, v| v[:count] == 1 }
     .sort_by { |_, v| v[:total] }].to_h
#⇒ {
#   "BOAT" => {
#    :count => 3,
#    :total => 1800
#  },
#  "HOUSE" => {
#    :count => 4,
#    :total => 500
#  }
# }
```

One might call `first` on result now, or use `max_by` instead of `sort_by` to retrieve just one max element.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that creates an array of hashes rather than selecting hashes from the given array.

**Code**

```
def doit(transactions)
  name, arr = transactions.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |g,h|
    h[g["name"]] << g["amount"] }.
    reject { |_,v| v.size == 1 }.
    min_by { |_,v| v.reduce(:+) }
    name ? arr.map { |v| { "amount"=>v, "name"=>name } } : []
end
```

**Examples**

```
doit(@transactions)
  #=> [{"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
  #    {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
  #    {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"}] 

doit([{"amount"=>-3000, "name"=>"CAR"}, {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
      {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE"}])  
      #=> []
```

**Explanation**

```
The steps for the first example are as follows.

a = @transactions.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |g,h|
  h[g["name"]] << g["amount"] }
  #=> {"CAR"=>[-3000], "BOAT"=>[-600, -600, -600], "HOUSE"=>[-125, -125, -125, -125]} 
b = a.reject { |_,v| v.size == 1 }
  #=> {"BOAT"=>[-600, -600, -600], "HOUSE"=>[-125, -125, -125, -125]} 
name, arr = b.min_by { |_,v| v.reduce(:+) }
  #=> ["BOAT", [-600, -600, -600]] 
arr
  #=> [-600, -600, -600] 
name
  #=> "BOAT" 
arr.map { |v| { "amount"=>v, "name"=>name } }
  #=> [{"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
  #    {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
  #    {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"}]
```

The expression

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }
  #=> {}
```

creates an empty hash with a default given by the block. Suppose we write

```
h[:dogs] += ["Saffi"]
  #=> ["Saffi"]
```

Ruby first expands this to

```
h[:dogs] = h[:dogs] + ["Saffi"]
```

Since `h` does not have a key `:dogs` (`h` is empty), the default is invoked for `h[:dogs]` on the right side of the equality, so the expression becomes

```
h[:dogs] = [] + ["Saffi"]
  #=> ["Saffi"]
```

Now

```
h #=> {:dogs=>["Saffi"]}
```

The expression

```
h[:dogs] << "Saffi"
  #=> ["Saffi"] 
h #=> {:dogs=>["Saffi"]}
```

is similar, in that `h[:dogs]` is set to `[]` before `"Saffi"` is appended to the empty array `h[:dogs]`. Now if we write

```
h[:dogs] << "Nina"
  #=> ["Saffi", "Nina"]
h #=> {:dogs=>["Saffi", "Nina"]}
```

the default block is not invoked since `h` now has a key `:dog`.

Another way of writing this is as follows.

```
def doit(transactions)
  name, arr = transactions.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
    (h[g["name"]] ||= []) << g["amount"] }.
    reject { |_,v| v.size == 1 }.
    min_by { |_,v| v.reduce(:+) }
    name ? arr.map { |v| { "amount"=>v, "name"=>name } } : []
end
```

if `h` does not have a key `g["name"]` (in which case `h[g["name"]] #=> nil`), this sets `h[g["name"]]` to `[]` before `g["amount"]` is appended.

Answer (score 1):

First step. Select "duplicated" transactions:

```
selected = @transactions.group_by { |el| el['name'] }
                        .select{ |k, v| v.size > 1 }
```

Second step. Find name of product with maximum amount (in that case with minimum, due to negative number):

```
selected.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), obj| obj[k] = v.map { |a| a['amount'] }.sum }
        .min_by { |k, v| v }.first
```

Update:

```
@transactions.group_by { |el| el['name'] }
             .each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), obj| obj[k] = v.map { |a| a['amount'] }.sum if v.size > 1 }
             .min_by { |k, v| v }.first
```